# How to restrict new apps using network data by default?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

Is it possible without third-party apps, through system configs? All news apps have the right to use both cellular and WLAN networks and doesn't look secure to me. Doing it manually isn't fun.

Thanks.

Comment: Google/Alphabet is making money from ads and ads are loaded via network. Now guess how likely it is to find an option to restrict system wide network access for (new) apps...

Comment: Any solution IMO would require a third-party support, even for using the inbuilt iptables.

Comment: You can use `iptables` if you have root. But that's too complicated to be easily manageable, such as when you switch from Wi-Fi to mobile data. Better is to use third party app as @Firelord suggested.